# Power Automate "Vlookup" using Sharepoint Lists - Vlookup resetting

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I have the below "Vlookup" , When a record gets submitted in list "Template" I want that to reflect in the list "Aug2021"(Created from an excel sheet) in the "Submitted" column as a "Yes" or "No".

Lookup with between "Project ID" in Template, and "Title" in Aug2021.

IT works fine for the first record submission into "Template", The submitted column shows a "Yes" nicely within list "Aug2021" .

However when I submit a 2nd record, the vlookup resets and that first record will no go to a No. Why is this?

[image]
[image]
[image: strong text]

This is what I mean - the flow re runs based on the new record.
[image]

Comment: Do you return all items in the list with "Get items" or do you use an advanced filter to return only the item whose Title matches to Project ID? Are you using the "ID" from the correct list in the "Update item" steps?

Comment: By what logic should the second record go to the No branch? The rule is that if Title from list AUG2021 is equal to Project ID from Template, then write a Yes. What is the scenario that would lead to a No?? You just said you submitted a 2nd record, but what were the values?

Comment: I see what you mean.  So yes if Project ID = Title, then Submitted = Yes otherwise No.

Answer (score 0):

When Power Automate does not execute the branch I "think" it "should" execute, that always is because the condition is not met.

The only way to troubleshoot that is to look into what is actually being fed into the Condition. At least while you're still developing.

Initialise two variables at the top, one for the Title and one for the Project ID. Write the Project ID into the variable as soon as you have it. Write the Title into the variable before the Condition step.

Now you can see in the flow run what the values are and you can see the reason for the condition branch being executed.

Also note that the For Each loop will run on all records that are returned bye the Get Items step. This looks like it may write a lot of records that don't match the title.

**Edit after comment**: You say that the list Aug2021 has 2000 items. Are you attempting to loop through all of them in the flow? That won't work, because the Get Items command only returns a maximum of 100 items.

The flow run screenshot shows that it processed **exactly** 100 items in the Apply to Each loop. Your screenshot only shows the first one.

Unfortunately, you did not follow my recommendation for troubleshooting, so you still don't know which values are being fed into the condition for each instance of the Apply to Each loop.

If you don't follow advice, I have no idea what else to write.

Comment: thanks. I think its looping each time based on the newly added project ID. Which is in turn making those old records in "Aug2021" switch to No.

Comment: I don't see how you would ever get to the No branch. Explain the logic. The Get Items returns a list of items. How many items are you returning? Are they all related to the trigger item? There seems to be a disconnect between what you expect to happen and what the flow is configured to do

Comment: List Aug2021 is many items, over 2000.  List Template is returning 2 to 3 items.  It looks like when a new record is being added, its only looking at the new record and redoing the vlookup (excluding existing records in template).   Logic is this, If Template.Project ID = Aug2021.Title then Aug2021.Submitted = Yes , if the record does not equal then Submitted = No.   Looks like its just re running for the entire process based 1 row/1 record each time it is ran, and forgets about hte previous records in Template.

Comment: I added to my answer